# How to load an array as a new column in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I generate an array as a time series calculation, and now I would like to include the generated array as a new column in my dataframe, which is loaded as a xlsx file. I will use it later as data provider in a function.

How can I do it??

```
import th

'Let´s suppose that time, PointA_ini, PointB_ini and Ge already are loaded'

#Here, I call a function which calculates an array over time. As a example, pressure over time
example = th.overtime(time, PointA_ini, PointB_ini, Ge)
Output = example.results()
print(Output)

# An array with a value each step is shown.
# Now, I want to include the array in my generated dataframe:
""" - - - - dframe- - - - - -"""
xls = pd.ExcelFile('Int1.xlsx')
df = xls.parse('Sheet1')
#HOW CAN I INCLUDE IN MY DF MY LIST AS A COLUMN???
```

Comment: What datatype is `Output`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, unless you defined `Salidas` elsewhere, you are going to have a problem. I assume you meant, `print(Output)`?

As for your question, if `Output` is already a list, all you have to do is assign it to a new column:

```
df['output'] = Output
```

If it is some other kind of iterable (such as a Numpy array), you will first need to wrap it in a `Series`:

```
df['output'] = pd.Series(Output)
```