# how to construct a list of integers

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I want to plot a figure: energy vs N. So how can I calculate the energy of different values of N ( argument in this function) and then plot the energy on Y-axis and each N value that corresponds to each energy value on the x-axis.

```py
 def energy(N, k, a=4.05):
    fcc = fcc100('Al', (1, 1, N), a=a, vacuum=7.5)
    fcc.center(axis=2)
    calc = GPAW(nbands=N * 3,
                kpts=(k, k, 1),
                h=0.25,
                txt='slab-%d.txt' % N)
    fcc.set_calculator(calc)
    e = fcc.get_potential_energy()
    calc.write('slab-%d.gpw' % N)
    return e
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it could be useful for you:

### Update 1:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def f(t):
    return np.exp(-t) * np.cos(2*np.pi*t)


t1 = np.arange(0.0, 3.0, 0.01)

plt.plot(t1, f(t1))
plt.show()
```

### Update 2:

Maybe you just want (I think so) to generate a list with the different values. Then, a simplified approach:

```
def fun(N):
    e = []
    for i in range(0, len(N)):
        e.append(calculation(N[i]))
    return e
```

### Update 3:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'N':[23,78,22,19,45,33,20],'Energy':[1000,2000,3000,4000,5000,5500,6000]})

    # a scatter plot comparing num_children and num_pets
df.plot(kind='scatter',x='N',y='Energy',color='red')
plt.show()
```

Comment: I suggest you to simplify your function, considering finally just and argument (N). Then, you can evaluate the function between your N range desired

Comment: Thank you for you swift reply.  i change the function with:                                  N = np.arange(0,10,1)
plt.plot(N, energy(N))
plt.show(). I had this error: "only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index"

Comment: You should define properly your functions. That's your problem. As an example, N = np.arange(0,10,1)

def energy(N):
    return 3*N


plt.plot(N, energy(N)) 
plt.show()

Comment: Now, you will need to develop properly your function. You can do whatever you want inside the function, but be careful that your return is just a function of N

Comment: I would like to create a list of N and then a list of energy on function of N energy(N) and then calling this two list as x, y in order to plot the figure. So to proceed

Comment: Then maybe your best choice is generate a dataframe, as you should do if you with time series analysis loading data from .csv, and then use it to plot the data calling a column 'N' as "x" axis and another 'energy' as "y" axis. The 'energy' one will be added in the dataframe [Here you can see how](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57565613/11935800) once you generate the list from your function results